# How to connect to LDAPserver using its credentials using c#

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to connect to ldap server using the following code.

```
        Dim xd As New XmlDocument()
        Dim domainAndUsername As String = String.Empty
        Dim userName As String = String.Empty
        Dim passWord As String = String.Empty
        Dim at As AuthenticationTypes = AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()



        domainAndUsername = "LDAP://MARS-AD\kumaravi:J647d197@ISXDC101.DC.MARS:389/OU=EXD,OU=People,OU=EMEAI,OU=Mars,OU=IT-Services,DC=Mars-AD,DC=Net"
        userName = "username"
        passWord = "password"

        at = AuthenticationTypes.Secure

        'Create the object necessary to read the info from the LDAP directory
        Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(domainAndUsername, userName, passWord, at)



        Dim mySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        Dim results As SearchResultCollection
        mySearcher.Filter = filter
```

It is giving the following error message.
"The server is not operational".

Comment: What kind of LDAP server?? Active Directory?? Your LDAP path is definitely not valid - it should be something like: `LDAP://domain/OU=EXD,OU=People,OU=EMEAI,OU=Mars,OU=IT-Services,DC=Mars-AD,DC=Net` or something like that - certainly no username/password in that LDAP string ....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context - this will automatically connect to the 
// current domain of your machine
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`